# Static results using scipy kstest

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I've been having trouble testing a sample sales distribution (stored in a pandas series) with a ks test. Using the test as described in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html). Here:

```
stats.kstest(sales.as_matrix(),'chi2',args=(10,) )
KstestResult(statistic=0.99991267392443384, pvalue=0.0)
```

The problem is that no mater which distribution I use ('norm','t','lognorm', etc) They all return the same values as above. I'm not sure what the problem is.

This is running on a jupyter notebook and python3, with anaconda, if it matters.

Here is an histogram of the "sales" series
[image: Histogram]

Comment: Maybe . . . the data doesn't fit that distribution?  Without a [mcve] it's difficult to tell anything about what's happening and why.

Comment: I tried providing an histogram. It looks like a lognormal to me, but if I test it i get same results. (This histogram is generated by simply using: sales.plot.hist(100))

Comment: It looks like you have a lot of samples.  With a big sample, your result is typical, unless the sample is actually from the the distribution that you are testing against.

Comment: its a 35k sample, i should reduce it then? what would be a good sample number?

Comment: Okay so I reduced the sample to 1k and with the help of scipy.fit got pretty accurate values for a fitted lognormal distribution, then used kstest and got KstestResult(statistic=0.03845, pvalue=0.101). Which are workable numbers. Howeve if I apply a normal or chi test it kinda "defaults" to 1 stat and 0 pvalue, I dont understand why this happens.

Comment: Each of those distributions will fit to different parameters, so if you're keeping the parameters and switching the distribution `kstest` will tell you your input distribution  is nothing like the data (which is what 1 stat 0 p basically means).